# Number of reduced residue classes with given order?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In general, is there a way to compute the number of reduced residue classes $\pmod n$ of a certain order?

For example, say $n=385=5\times7\times11$. Then
$$
(\mathbb Z/385\mathbb Z)^\times\cong(\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)^\times\times (\mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z)^\times\times (\mathbb Z/11\mathbb Z)^\times.
$$
In $(\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)^\times$ there are $1,1,2$ elements of orders $1,2,4$.

In $(\mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z)^\times$ there are $1,1,2,2$ elements of orders $1,2,3,6$.

In $(\mathbb Z/11\mathbb Z)^\times$ there are $1,1,4,4$ elements of orders $1,2,5,10$.

Then, if I wanted to see how many elements of order $4$ (say) there were in $(\mathbb Z/385\mathbb Z)^\times$, I can 'brute' force and check all the triples $(a\pmod5,b\pmod7,c\pmod{11})$ for which $\text{lcm}(\text{ord}_5a,\text{ord}_7b,\text{ord}_{11}c)=4$ and conclude that there are $8$ elements of order $4$.

Is there a faster method/theorem to compute this? And if there isn't, what about for $\lambda(385)=60$, the maximum order? Is there a way to compute how many elements there are of order $60$?

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure about the first part. The "nice" thing is that you can just focus on the orders and then calculate how many elements of a given order there are. Since the group of units mod $p$ is cyclic, the number of elements of order $n$ is equal to the number of solutions of the equation

$$ kn  \equiv 0 \pmod{p-1}$$

such that $k m \neq 0 \pmod{p-1}$ for any $m < n$.

For the last part, note that you want to calculate the number of generators for each prime. The number of generators $\mod p$ is equal to $\phi (\phi(p)) = \phi(p-1)$. Hence, if $n$ is a square-free product of primes then

$$\lambda (n) = \prod _{p \mid n} \phi(p-1)$$

Note the square-free condition ensures that the $\mod p$ groups are cyclic. Otherwise, it gets a bit messy and I haven't given it much thought.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is well known that if $n=\prod_{i=1}^{t}p_i^{\alpha_i}$ ,

then $\phi(n)=n\prod_{i=1}^{t}(1-\frac{1}{p_i})$